# Why two different outputs?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am novice in programming. I have written a program and confused in concepts of pointers.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char c[]="hello";
    char *a=c;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    int arr[]={1,2,3,5};
    int *p=arr;
    cout<<p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I print a, it prints `hello` but when I print p it print the address. Why?

Comment: First of all, do you know which language you are actually trying to learn here?

Comment: @AbhishekShukla Dude its c++

Comment: So you should rethink it, as it is not C.

Comment: The `<bits/stdc++.h>` is an invalid header for C.  It is a compiler specific header for C++ and should not be used.

Comment: If it is C my whole life is lie :(((

Comment: Regarding `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, [this is bad form.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) Worse, combined with `using namespace std;`, the entire standard library is included and pulled into the global namespace. This can result in a minefield of identifiers that can collide with what you define in your code resulting in some very hard to interpret mystery errors. It is unlikely to bite in trivial code like this, but when it does, wowzers.

Answer (score 2):

`std::ostream` has overload for `const char*` to display C-string.
`int*` would use the `void*` one which print the address.

Comment: with printf, it gives same result.

Comment: Which format do you use ? and BTW, one question by question (and `printf` would suit more with C tag).

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
 char c[]="hello";
 char *a=c;
 printf("%s\n",a);
 int arr[]={1,2,3,5};
 int *p=arr;
 cout<<p<<endl;
 return 0;
}`

Comment: @AbhishekShukla `%s` tells `printf` that the variable is a null-terminated char array and is to be printed as one would a string. You said print a string, you provided a string, the program printed a string. Look at the `printf` documentation for the `%p` format specifier if you want to print the address of the array. Side note: Because `printf` doesn't know what the type of the provided variables are, you can pass it an integer and it will attempt to interpret it as a pointer to a `char` array and print it as a string to not-so-comical results.